# TFS Query result column width automatically resizing

Tags: tfs, tfs-web-access

TFS 2013 in IE 11
I have a custom query and this is what I see in the header for columns:

[image]

The columns I want are there but the width is automatically reduced. As seen it sets to -1.
[image]

Once I drag the State column, etc. manually I see the details.

[image]

I have manually tried adjusting the width but it's not persisted. As soon as I move out of the query and go back, the width resets by itself.

I have other custom queries and they all work fine. Not sure what is wrong with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is causing the issue is the resizing of the column by dragging it.
So once I set the column width manually by entering value in the width column, it is persisted even after I close the browser and come back.

[image]

But now if I go and change the width by dragging the column header, the width goes back to -1 and will never persist unless I go and set it manually.

[image]

Seems to be some bug within TFS.

Comment: I have to say that, yes, I can reproduce your issue in my TFS2013 web access. How about you submit your feature request on the Microsoft Connect site: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/LoadSubmitFeedbackForm